# Uso de Nested Attributes com tabela de relacionamento "has_many through"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho o seguinte problema, possuo um relacionamento:

```
class Servidor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lotacoes, :through=>:servidor_lotacoes
  has_many :servidor_lotacoes
end



class Lotacao < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :servidores,:through=>:servidor_lotacoes
  has_many :servidor_lotacoes
end


class ServidorLotacao < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :lotacao
  belongs_to :servidor
end
```

Onde `ServidorLotacao` possui um atributo extra `tipo:integer`

Como posso criar um formulário (ex `collection_select`) para gerenciar esse relacionamento em Servidor, onde ainda possa passar o tipo para ser armazenado na tabela de relacionamento?

Pensei em criar 3 selects multiplos (um pra cada tipo) mas pegar essas informações do outro lado está meio complexo.

Mais ou menos meu código:

```
    <% ServidorLotacao.tipos.to_h.each_pair do |tipo_nome, tipo_codigo| %>
    <div class="field" >
      <%= f.label :lotacao_ids, tipo_nome %><br>

      <%= collection_select(:servidor, "lotacao_ids[#{tipo_codigo}]", 
        @lotacoes, 
        :id, :nome, {:selected => @servidor.lotacao_ids_for(tipo_codigo), :include_blank => true}, {:multiple => true, class: "select2_1",  style:"width: 100%;"}) %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
```

E o resultado em meu controller

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"r5KaLCrb1PR//q4HZ0p30dUeK1OHE7cjmtoken=",
 "servidor"=>
  {"nome"=>"123412312",
   "tipo"=>"1",
   "lotacao_ids"=>{"1"=>[""], "2"=>["", "87"], "3"=>[""]},
   "contatos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"telefone"=>"(063) 8132-9584", "id"=>"605"}},
   "matricula"=>"56830",
   "cpf"=>"4539"},
 "action"=>"update",
 "controller"=>"servidores",
 "id"=>"340"}
```

Onde `lotacao_ids` são os Ids de minhas lotações agrupado pelo tipo. Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1):

Seria isso que tu quer?

```
# servidor_lotacao_controller.rb
def new
  @servidor_lotacao = ServidorLotacao.new
end

# new.html.erb
= form_for(@servidor_lotacao) do
  = f.label :servidor
  = f.collection_select (...)

  = f.label :lotacao
  = f.collection_select (...)

  = f.label :tipo
  = f.text_field :tipo

  = f.submit "Salvar"
end
```

Se não é isso que tu quer, edite sua pergunta, pois não está suficientemente claro para mim.